# PHP - Split tags and concatenate with a space

Tags: php

I have a list of tags that are separated by a `,` I have split them and now I want to concatenate them with a space in between so they can by used in the `data-tags` attribute. How can I do this?

```
<div data-tags="<?php foreach ($lab->tags()->split(',') as $tag): ?>
   <?php echo str::slug($tag)?>
<?php endforeach ?>" class="lab-cnt em-below">
```

This is the current output

```
// data-tags="pavillionindustrialcommercial"
```

The ideal output is

```
// data-tags="pavillion industrial commercial"
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I've answered the question, if it solves your issue, please mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `explode` and `implode` functions:

```
$tags = $lab->tags();
// 'pavillion,industrial,commercial'

$tags = explode(',', 'pavillion,industrial,commercial');
// ['pavillion', 'industrial', 'commercial']

$tags = array_map(str::slug, $tags);
// slugified ['pavillion', 'industrial', 'commercial']

$tags = implode($tags, ' ');
// 'pavillion industrial commercial'
```

Comment: Had this in mind to add to my answer, but chose to stick to user's code. My bad ;)

Answer (score 3):

Add a space in your echo statement on line 2 using a concatenation operator and space enclosed in quotes `." "`-

**Like this -**

```
<?php echo str::slug($tag)." "?>
```

So your code will now become -

```
<div data-tags="<?php foreach ($lab->tags()->split(',') as $tag): ?>
   <?php echo str::slug($tag)." "?>
<?php endforeach ?>" class="lab-cnt em-below">
```

Comment: Added more info. @Martin

Answer (score 1):

The simple way just add a space character in the end of each echo `' '`

```
<div data-tags="<?php foreach ($lab->tags()->split(',') as $tag): ?>

     <?php echo str::slug($tag).' ' ?>

<?php endforeach ?>" class="lab-cnt em-below">
```